# Word for simultaneously smiling at something heartwarming and exhaling air involuntarily

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What is the word or phrase for that action when someone smiles at something heartwarming and exhales air involuntarily at the same time? It's not a laugh or even a chuckle, more like a hum with no vocalization.

Answer (score 1):

There are many synonyms for *sigh* but none seem to capture the appreciative nuance that you seek. In some contexts you may be able to use *purr*.

> = (of a cat) to make a soft, low, continuous sound
>
> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/purr)

> = a low vibratory murmur typical of an apparently contented or pleased cat
>
> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/purr)

The duration of the sound is not defined. Although having feline origins, the word has sometimes been extended to describe a soft appreciative sound:

> I could almost hear Julie’s purr of appreciation at my “supplementary”: “As St Augustine reminded us: ‘Lord, make me pure, but just not yet’.”
>
> [Catholic Herald](https://catholicherald.co.uk/what-is-time-without-children/)

> It is just that he is never more vulnerable than when he has just provoked a purr of appreciation
>
> [Daily Mail](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/sport/cricket/article-7168393/Same-old-James-Vince-batsman-blows-chance-against-Sri-Lanka.html)

Comment: I notice that no attempt is made to render the sound using IPA. The CH example shows that the noise is possibly subliminal. But the word works.